# Several targets in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm starting a project where I will have several targets.
My question is how do I get an value from the right info.plist?

Say I have three plists...

> Target1-info.plist / Target2-info.plist / Target3-info.plist

Is there any 'wildcard' that can be used when using...

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("*-info", ofType: "plist")
```

Comment: in a certain _target_, under the _Bundle Settings_ / _Packaging_, you can find the associated info `.plist` file's name; you need to set up the desired file's name there and in the code you don't need to worry about which target you are in, the compiler will embed the correct / right file for your current target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values of the plist directly by using `NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("SOME_KEY")`
Just replace `"SOME_KEY"` with the key you want.

e.g:
`NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleDevelopmentRegion")`

Answer (score 2):

Info.plist files are some kind of special resources in Xcode. They are not copied like the other resources during build phase, and they have no overwritable build rule. Xcode copies `TargetX-Info.plist` as `Info.plist` to the resulting bundle of the appropriate target.

Thus, you can only access `Info.plist` and not `TargetX-Info.plist` during run-time of your apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("*-info"", ofType: "plist") {
            myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
```